# How to define pwd as a variable in Unix shell

Tags: shell, unix, pwd

I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
dir=$pwd
echo $dir

/bin/env/####/ --id --edition dir- $dir
```

I want to paste the current working directory into the above script.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The current directory is already in a variable, called `PWD`, and it is [automatically set by the shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/cd.html):

```
echo "$PWD"
```

You could also:

```
dir=$(pwd)
echo "$dir"
```

Or you could use these in your script without storing in additional variables:

```
/bin/env/####/ --id --edition-dir "$PWD"
/bin/env/####/ --id --edition-dir "$(pwd)"
```

For your information: every time you change directory, whether in an interactive shell or a script, the shell sets the value of the `PWD` variable to the current directory, and the value of `OLDPWD` to the previous directory.

Well, usually. As [@WilliamPursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell) pointed out, `OLDPWD` is not standard, so it might not be available in all shells.

Comment: how is the pwd set implicitly? How does the internals work?

Comment: @Sathish see the link on the first line of the answer.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
dir="$PWD"
```

or

```
dir="$(pwd)"
```

you may want to have double quotes too if your path contained special chars, like spaces.

Comment: superr thanks a lott for these answers it really workedd