# Is the environmental variable PWD always defined in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables

Question: Is the environment variable PWD always defined under Linux independent of the command shell (neglecting non-command shells)? In other words, will a command like "ls $PWD" always run?

Comment: I would rather rely on the output from the `pwd` or `pwd -P` command. As in `ls $(pwd)`.

Comment: @Tanktalus `pwd -P` can be useful indeed, but regarding `ls $(pwd)`, if the current directory contains spaces or other special characters, that won't work unless you do `ls "$(pwd)"`

Comment: @Tanktalus, `ls "$(pwd)"` is much slower to execute than `ls "$PWD"` -- the former requires a subshell (thus, a pipe pair's creation and a `fork()` in bash) just to get the output of a copy of `pwd` run in a subprocess; in the latter, the only subprocess is the copy of `ls` itself.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to define pwd as a variable in Unix shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20839678/608639).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Posix compliant shells will set this environment variable.  Look for PWD in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/cd.html

> PWD
>       This variable shall be set as specified in the DESCRIPTION. If an application sets or unsets the value of PWD , the behavior of cd is
>   unspecified.

or section 2.5.3 "Shell variables" in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xcu_chap02.html

> Variables shall be initialized from the environment...  If a variable
>   is initialized from the environment, it shall be marked for export
>   immediately
>
> PWD
>       Set by the shell to be an absolute pathname of the current working directory,

Comment: Yes this is the answer I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the environment variable `PWD` always defined under Linux independent of the command shell?

No, and I don't see why this could be the case, because the `PWD` variable is automatically updated (at shell initialization and) after using the `cd` command, which is precisely a **shell builtin**.

Relevant documentation about `PWD` can be found e.g. in:

- the [list of Bash variables detailed in the Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-PWD),
- the ["Pwd" article in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pwd#Working_directory_shell_variables),
- or the [documentation of cd in the POSIX Standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html)

Below is a sample Bash session to exemplify the link between `PWD` and `cd`:

```
/$ echo "$SHELL"
/bin/bash
/$ echo "$PWD"
/
/$ cd usr/bin/
/usr/bin$ echo "$PWD"
/usr/bin
```

> In other words, will a command like `ls $PWD` always run?

Actually, the `$PWD` syntax corresponds to a [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), so `ls $PWD` couldn't be properly evaluated without a shell.

A remark in passing: it is strongly recommended to double-quote your shell variables, writing thereby `ls "$PWD"` in this case, to avoid troubles if the variable contains spaces or other special characters.

Comment: It's also set on shell initialization, so issuing a `cd` first is not required

Comment: @thatotherguy indeed, I've edited my answer to add your remark.